# Holoviewsでグラフを複数表示させたとき、軸範囲を同期させない方法

Tags: python

## 環境

- Python 3.7
- Holoviews 1.10.7

## やりたいこと

Holoviewsで、グラフを横に2つ並べて表示させたいです。

```
import math
xs1 = range(-10,11)
xs2 = range(-5,5)
ys1 = [100-x**2 for x in xs1]
ys2 = [10*math.sin(x) for x in xs2]
c1 = hv.Curve((xs1, ys1))
c2 = hv.Curve((xs2, ys2))
c1+c2
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、上記のコードだと、左側と右側のグラフの軸の範囲は同期されています。左側のグラフの軸範囲を変更すると、右側も軸範囲も変わります。

以下のコードのように、左側のグラフと右側のグラフで、軸名を変更すれば、軸範囲は同期しないことが分かりました。

```
c1 = hv.Curve((xs1, ys1),"x1","y1")
c2 = hv.Curve((xs2, ys2),"x2","y2")
```

## 質問

左側のグラフと右側のグラフで軸名が同じ状態で、軸範囲を同期させないようにするには、どうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%%opts Layout [shared_axes=False]

xs1 = range(-10,11)
xs2 = range(-5,5)
ys1 = [100-x**2 for x in xs1]
ys2 = [10*math.sin(x) for x in xs2]
c1 = hv.Curve((xs1, ys1))
c2 = hv.Curve((xs2, ys2))

c1+c2
```

でどうでしょうか

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。

Comment: マジックコマンド`%%opts'を使いたくないので、以下のコードを書きました.
```
layout = c1+c2
layout.options(shared_axes=False)
```

Comment: ちなみに、`shared_axes=False`に関する情報はどこに記載してありますか？Holoviewsでやりたいことを探すには、どのページをどのように見ればよいかなどの参考にしたいです。